# Select in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to create a function in HASKELL that takes a predicate and two lists as arguments and returns a list composed of elements from the second list in those positions where the predicate, when applied to the element in the corresponding positions of the first list, returns True. What I have so far is...

```
select :: (t -> Bool) -> [t] -> [a] -> [a]
select _ [] = []  
select p (x:xs)   
    | p x       = x : select p xs  
    | otherwise = select p xs
```

p11tests = [select even [1..26] "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" == "bdfhjlnprtvxz", select (<= 'g') "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" [1..26] == [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]]

p11tests is where I test the function. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Since you work with two inputs, the patterns look like `select _ [] [] = ...`; `select _ (x:xs) (y:ys)`.

Answer (score 1):

You are not working with two lists. Your function is in essence a `filter` function where you retrieve all items `x` in the (first) list that satisfy the predicate `p`.

You want to check if the predicate matches for the item of the first list, and in that case yield the item in the second list, so:

```
select :: (t -> Bool) -> [t] -> [a] -> [a]
select _ [] [] = []
select _ (_:_) [] = []
select _ [] (_:_) = []
select p (x:xs) (y:ys)
    | p x = …
    | otherwise = …
```

where I leave filling in `…` as an exercise.

You can also work with a combination of `zip`, `filter` and `map` where you first `zip` the two items together, then filter items where the first item of the 2-tuples satisifies the predicate, and then you map on the second element. So something like:

```
select :: (t -> Bool) -> [t] -> [a] -> [a]
select p xs = map snd . filter (p . fst) . zip xs
```

Comment: (This is just for fun. Beginners feel free to skip this comment.) Another cute solution that may (or may not) have slightly different performance: `concat . zipWith (\x y -> [y | p x]) xs`. This requires only two passes, rather than three, and does not allocate/destructure any tuples. Buuuut it may also be that it's harder to fuse, and it does allocate/destructure lists. It's possible to fix those two problems, but at a serious readability cost; something like `foldr ($) [] . zipWith (\x y -> if p x then (y:) else id) xs`, for example, should fuse nicely and not do any extra allocation.

Comment: @DanielWagner Willem's implementation produces perfectly good Core. If marked `INLINABLE` (to try to fuse with its surroundings), it admittedly won't look so lovely, although it might clean up later. I was surprised by how *bad* the Core looks in your first suggestion. Notably, `++ @ a_aGV (GHC.Types.[] @ a_aGV) (go2_a1BN ipv1_a1BT ipv3_a1BY)` is just ridiculous. Your second suggestion looks pretty good, except in source.

Comment: @dfeuer When you say "Willem's implementation", are you talking about the first implementation or the second?

Comment: @DanielWagner, uh, the second. Though I imagine the first will be just fine if you don't worry about fusing with anything else. I'm thinking someone should file a ticket about why your first implementation compiles so badly.

Comment: @DanielWagner, https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/19732

Comment: @dfeuer Well, if that's the core for my first version, that doesn't... actually look *that* bad. `[] ++ xs` is a bit unfortunate, for sure, but not catastrophic -- it's not as if it suddenly becomes quadratic or anything like that. I'll admit I can't read the `True` branch well enough to know whether my concerns about allocating/destructuring lists are actually justified in that case or not, though.